# Cron not running while the commands are fine, why?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cron

I have the following cron that checks if my Neo4J DB is running and if it's down, it shuts down the Node.Js app, then restarts the db and then starts the app again. The second line is the backup script.

`* * * * * /home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-2.0.1/bin/neo4j status || /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/forever stopall && /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/forever start $HOME/webapps/infranodus/infranodus/app.js && /home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-2.0.1/bin/neo4j start
10 14 * * * ~/webapps/infranodus/bin/backup`

When I run the code myself from the shell, such as

`/home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-2.0.1/bin/neo4j status || /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/forever stopall && /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/forever start $HOME/webapps/infranodus/infranodus/app.js && /home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-2.0.1/bin/neo4j start`

It does everything well.

But the cron doesn't do that check every minute and doesn't relaunch anything...

PS When I do `crontab -l` it lists the above and I edit it using `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` - just in case that matters...

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Neo4J is a Java program and it was not running from cron correctly – not the same environment variables.

What I did was to change cron so that it runs a shell script

`* * * * * ~/webapps/infranodus/bin/checkdb`

and in side that `checkdb` script I have:

`#!/bin/bash -l
/home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-2.0.1/bin/neo4j start`

which simply attempts to restart the DB (if it started already it will simply not start because it's the same process)

So that's a workaround and the  first line - to use `bash` shell is very important - so it stays with the same params.